# SSRS grouping - dataset values in header and footer

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports

Been pulling my hair out over an issue in SSRS.  I"m converting Crystal reports to SSRS.  What I have is a Dataset in a  table in my detail area of my SSRS report, grouping on a certain field, displays data and summaries by group, no problem.  What i need to have however, is data from that same group in the page header and footer, sometimes certain values as a summation of a numerical value from the dataset **for that same group**.  When I attempt this (i.e. = Sum(Fields!payment_amt.Value, "DataSet1"), I get the summation of that value for the *entire* dataset, not just for the group in question.  I need it for just the group. in the page header and footer.  Likewise doing something like First(Fields!columnname.Value, "DataSet1") will only display the initial value of the comlumname for the dataset, and does not page to the next value in the grouping as I scroll through the pages

SSRS will not allow you to put a table or subreport in the header or footer, so i cannot simulate the data retrieval in the header and footer to match the specified grouping in the detail area.  It seems Crystal Reports and other report tools can handle something like this just fine, with sort of "free form" in the headers and footers, which display the proper data in the page headers and footers base on the specified groupings.

SSRS seems to rigid with requiring the Table Layout for datasets for grouping, not allowing for free form style.  is there a way around this?

Comment: Can you post some screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing exactly what you are trying to achieve I can't give a specific answer but you can reference textbox names including the textboxes that make up your tablix.

So, if you have a tablix and one of the columns showed, say, an account balance. Click the cell in question and get it's name from the properties window. If it's called, say `Textbox99` then in your header you can refernce is with something like

```
=FIRST(ReportItems!TextBox99.Value)
```

Other types of aggregations are available..